# Symfony 2 - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SessionHandlerInterface in C:\...\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 532

Tags: php, symfony

After reinstalling my wamp environment this error message is showing on screen after I open app_dev.php:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SessionHandlerInterface in C:...\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 532

Does anyone have any clue what is going wrong?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I solved it clearing the cache:

```
app/console cache:clear
```

Comment: Was this a permanent fix? Or did you need to do anything else? i.e - update your Symfony 2 installation.

Answer (score 22):

PHP version **5.4** introduced a new session management system based on an interface called `SessionHandlerInterface` and it would seem that your Symfony2 code declares a class with the very same name in the global namespace, so there is a name clash.

Here are the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

> SessionHandlerInterface is an interface which defines a prototype for
>   creating a custom session handler. In order to pass a custom session
>   handler to session_set_save_handler() using its OOP invocation, the
>   class must implement this interface.

Comment: maybe cause it was just 'informative' and not a 'solution' per se... but have my love :)

Comment: I proposed a change to add a namespace to the SessionHandlerInterface, however there seems to be BC break with 5.3 for some reason. Travis build fails...

Answer (score 14):

The simple clear cache didn't work for me. It required that the production cache be cleared using the command below.

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: waht do you mean with --no-debug ?

Answer (score 7):

Just try to clear the Symfony2 cache with the one (or all) the commands below :

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug (on production mode)
```

or / and

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug (on development mode)
```

Answer (score 4):

Only this worked for me `rm -rf app/cache/*`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have defined namespace in your interface SessionHandlerInterface

**EX:**

```
namespace app\cache\dev;
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having caching issues even when using app_dev.php.  I would change a route but it wouldn't update when I tried accessing it via a browser.

I tried commenting out the anything that had cache in it (as stated above). None of that worked.

If I ran the console cache:clear it would fix it, but the next routing change would break again.  I had to run cache:clear with every save, which was ridiculous.

My issue turned out that because I was working remotely over SFTP, PHP Storm (my editor) was "preserving timestamp" in its deployment configuration.  Once I changed that configuration the issues went away.  Apparently there is some caching going on that is looking at the file timestamps, even in the dev environment.