# Symfony2 project moved from MAMPP to AMPP - many errors

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ampps

I needed to reinstall my Mac and now I'm using AMPP instead of MAMP for my Apache and SQL server.

After I put my complete Symfony Projekt ( including composer.phar file ) in my www folder and launched it on localhost/www/Seotool/web/app_dev.php I get this exception:

> FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class SessionHandlerInterface in /Applications/AMPPS/www/Seotool/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1072

I also cleared the cache.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Try reinstalling the dependencies. Your class cache file is created in a Composer post-install hook, so the caches are then rebuilt.

Comment: What do you exactly mean? How can I reinstall it?

Comment: you could just clean the `vendor/` dir and then run `php composer.phar --install`

Comment: I did. In the console following exception:   [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command. And in the browser: FatalErrorException: Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class SessionHandlerInterface in /Applications/AMPPS/www/Seotool/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1072

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony 2 - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SessionHandlerInterface in C:\...\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line 532](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689307/symfony-2-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-sessionhandlerinterface-in-c)

Comment: Symfony2 worked till yesterday on PHP 5.5.3.
After clearing cache following exception is thrown: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Annotations\token_get_all() in /Applications/AMPPS/www/Seotool/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/TokenParser.php on line 56

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Annotations\token_get_all() in /Applications/AMPPS/www/Seotool/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/TokenParser.php on line 56

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue due following steps:

My Macbook Pro was with the Beta Yosemite OS. I deleted the recovery partition, installed OSX 10.8 Lion on my MB. After that I upgradet to the OSX 10.9 Mavericks. Then I downloaded MAMP, installed it, renamed the MAC PHP to PHP.BACKUP, made a symlink from php to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php , restartet apache, downloaded composer to htdocs directory, created a new Symfony2 project, setted the user and group of this project with chown -R user:group myproject , put umask(0000) into app/console and web/app_dev.php , launched it in my Browser. It worked. So I putted my backup of my old Symfony Project, putted it into my htdocs folder, setted new correct user and group settings for this project with chown -R user:group oldsymfonyproject and voila - all worked like before :) Just need to create the database again :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the correct PHP installation. Check that your `phpinfo` has a `ctype` block and that the `ctype functions` is `enabled`.

It's possible that your PHP was compiled with `--disable-ctype` flag. How did you install it? Was it the system built-in version?

Try installing PHP with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and mind the `--disable-ctype` flag.

Comment: I updated my Question. Problem with ctype is solved. New exception...

PHP Version is 5.5 , ctype is enabled.