# Doctrine PHP DataFixture : "Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a PHP class to generate some fixtures :

```
namespace DashboardBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use DashboardBundle\Entity\Property;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoadPropertyData extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface, OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    /** @var  ContainerInterface */
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $properties = $this->container->get('dashboard.properties_generator');

        foreach ($properties as $key => $propertyConfig) {
            $property = new Property();
            $property->setName($key);
            $property->setType($propertyConfig);

            $this->addReference('property-' . $key, $property);

            $manager->persist($property);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return  1;
    }
}
```

But I get this error :

```
➜  dashboard git:(guillaume) ✗ bin/console -v fixtures:load

/* ... some stuff ... */

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                              
Compile Error: Cannot redeclare class DashboardBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadPropertyData
```

The namespace seems and the class name seems correct. There is no other file in the *DashboardBundle\DataFixtures\ORM* directory.

I tried to restart the servers (PHP-FPM and Nginx), I tried to clear the Symfony cache, but there is no effect.

In brief, I have no idea why Symfony throws this exception.
Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: What is the file name containing the class (no case issu here) ? what is your os ? are you using an APC class loader in your app ?

Comment: @n3k The filename is /src/DashboardBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadPropertyData.php
My OS : MacOS (but I use Docker instances based on Debian for local servers). No APC class loader.

Comment: Try with `class LoadPropertyData extends AbstractFixture implements ContainerAwareInterface` to see what happens. Also search `DataFixtures` in here for some examples: http://www.inanzzz.com/

Comment: @BentCoder I tried to remove/change implemented and extended classes, the problem is still the same.

Comment: Did you found ?

Comment: @COil No, still stuck :/

Comment: Are you using PhpStorm? Search the whole project for 'LoadPropertyData'. I know you said you did it, but a [similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689307/symfony-2-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class-sessionhandlerinterface-in-c) was solved by clearing the cache